# appendChild failed appending same element to one of the same class elements?

Tags: javascript

Please see [here](https://www.weddingguestdresses.com/products/womens-sleeveless-summer-knee-length-mermaid-formal-contrast-dress).

We have this code in javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  let source_elem = document.querySelector('.ProductMeta__Description .Rte .TableWrapper table');

  let size_table = source_elem.cloneNode( true );

  let hooks = document.querySelectorAll('.product-desc-table-clone');
  console.log('size: ' + hooks.length);
  for (i = 0; i < hooks.length; ++i) {
    hooks[i].appendChild( size_table );
    console.log(i);
  }

});
```

Which appends a size chart table to 2 div elements with class `product-desc-table-clone`. Oddly only the 2nd element got appended with the table.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Node.appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, ***`appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position***.

You can either use `innerHTML` or [**Element.insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

**Demo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  let source_elem = document.querySelector('.ProductMeta__Description .Rte .TableWrapper table');
  let size_table = source_elem.cloneNode(true);
  let hooks = document.querySelectorAll('.product-desc-table-clone');
  console.log('size: ' + hooks.length);
  for (i = 0; i < hooks.length; i++) {
    hooks[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', size_table.outerHTML);
    console.log(i);
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="ProductMeta__Description">
  <div class="Rte">
    <div class="TableWrapper">
       <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-desc-table-clone"></div>
<div class="product-desc-table-clone"></div>
```

Comment: (Doesn’t have anything to do with cloneNode in particular though - with a _new_ node via `document.createElement` instead, the issue would be exactly the same. `appendChild` simply removes a node from its current location, if it was in the DOM already.)

Comment: @CBroe, you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)